# Check if array has the key value pairs of the other array

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I have two sets of arrays:

```
var a = [1, 2, {a: 1, b:2}, 3];
var b = [1, {a: 1, b: 2}, 3};
```

If array a has ALL (EXACT) the properties and values of array b (including objects) then it will increment count by 1. Otherwise, if array a has only some properties and some values doesn't match, it will just exit and do nothing.

As an example:

```
var a = [1, 2, {a: 1, b:2}, 3];
var b = [1, {a: 1, b: 2}, 3}; 
// return true / count++

var a = [1, 2, 3, {a: 1, b: 4}];
var b = [1, 2, {a: 1, b: 6}, 3];
return false / no count
```

Here's my program first:

```
for(var i = 0; i < mainArr[i]; i++){
if(arr.includes(mainArr[i])){
      count++;
    }

if(typeof(mainArr[i]) === 'object' && typeof(arr[i]) === 'object'){
      for(var mainArrProp in mainArr[i]){
        for(var arrProp in arr[i]){
          if(arr[i].hasOwnProperty(mainArrProp) && arr[i][arrProp] === mainArr[i][mainArrProp]){
            count++;
          }
        }
      }
    }
}
```

Any way to fix this?

Comment: What’s the problem, and what’s supposed to happen? I think one of those is described in your question, but I can’t tell which one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you can use es6, you can leverage some of the new methods to make a (relatively) short function to do this. Specifically we would make use of the array `includes`, `every`, and `some` methods to check for shallow object equality:

```js
function getIncrementValue(set, subset) {
    for (let item of subset) {
        if (typeof item === "object") {
            // Special case if looking at an object. I am assuming object is always shallow.
            if (!set.some(otherItem => typeof otherItem === "object" && Object.keys(otherItem).length === Object.keys(item).length && Object.keys(otherItem).every(key => (key in item) && item[key] === otherItem[key]))) return 0;
        } else {
            if (!set.includes(item)) return 0;
        }
    }
    
    return 1;
}

// So for your arrays:

var a1 = [1, 2, {a: 1, b:2}, 3];
var b1 = [1, {a: 1, b: 2}, 3]; 
// return true / count++

var a2 = [1, 2, 3, {a: 1, b: 4}];
var b2 = [1, 2, {a: 1, b: 6}, 3];
// return false / no count

console.log(getIncrementValue(a1, b1)) // returns 1;
console.log(getIncrementValue(a2, b2)) // returns 0;
```

This is pretty straightforward except for that one long line that checks for object equality. But all that says is:

If there is not some element of `set` that:

- is an object, and
- the element and our current item have the same number of keys, and
- every key of that element is a key of our current item, and
- the values for each key are the same

Then return 1.

Answer (score 0):

You're following totally wrong way, you don't need to work with regular `count++` in your case, you should better decrease by one and return, if any value from arrayA doesn't exist in arrayB. I rewrote the method with explanation of each row, I think, it should be clear what's going on. I also noticed, that you write in ES5, but you also use `includes()`, it's a ES6 feature, good to know. I have left `includes()` in my implementation too. My method returns 1 if all values from the first array exists in the second, and returns 0 if not. Here it is:

```js
function test(a, b) {
  var count = 1,
      /* "aValues" will contain both single numbers and object values from "a" array */
      aValues = createHomogeneousArray(a),
      /* "bValues" will contain both single numbers and object values from "b" array */
      bValues = createHomogeneousArray(b);
  /* Check does each value of "aValues" exists in "bValues" array, if not - return "count--" (will be equal to "0") */
  aValues.forEach(function(item) {
    if (!bValues.includes(item)) {
      return count--
    }
  });
  
  /* If nothing was returned yet, return count (is equal to "1") */
  return count;
}

function createHomogeneousArray(arr) {
  var finalArr = [];
  /* Iterate through array */
  arr.forEach(function(item) {
    /* Check is object */
    if (typeof item === 'object') {
      /* If object - get all values of this object as array */
      var arrOfObjValues = Object.values(item);
      /* Iterate through this array with object values */
      arrOfObjValues.forEach(function(value) {
        /* Push each value of above array to the "finalArr" array, which contains ALL values of the array, passed to this function */
        finalArr.push(value);
      });
    /* Check is number */
    } else if (typeof item === 'number') {
      /* Push all regular numbers to final array */
      finalArr.push(item);
    }
  });
  /* Return "finalArr" array */
  return finalArr;
}

console.log(test(
  [1, 2, {a: 1, b:2}, 3],
  [1, {a: 1, b: 2}, 3]
))

console.log(test(
  [1, 2, 3, {a: 1, b: 4}],
  [1, 2, {a: 1, b: 6}, 3]
))
```

Don't be scared of the size of the code, it's much smaller without comments:

```js
function test(a, b) {
  var count = 1,
      aValues = createHomogeneousArray(a),
      bValues = createHomogeneousArray(b);
  aValues.forEach(function(item) {
    if (!bValues.includes(item)) {
      return count--
    }
  });
  return count;
}

function createHomogeneousArray(arr) {
  var finalArr = [];
  arr.forEach(function(item) {
    if (typeof item === 'object') {
      var arrOfObjValues = Object.values(item);
      arrOfObjValues.forEach(function(value) {
        finalArr.push(value);
      });
    } else if (typeof item === 'number') {
      finalArr.push(item);
    }
  });
  return finalArr;
}

console.log(test(
  [1, 2, {a: 1, b:2}, 3],
  [1, {a: 1, b: 2}, 3]
))

console.log(test(
  [1, 2, 3, {a: 1, b: 4}],
  [1, 2, {a: 1, b: 6}, 3]
))
```